# Returning a single field from a postgresql function with an alias?

Tags: function, postgresql, return-type

How can I return a single column from a postgresql function, but alias the column as well?

The problem is this:
In the documentation
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html
it has the following example.

```
CREATE FUNCTION one() RETURNS integer AS $$
    SELECT 1 AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This returns a field named after the function "one". I am wondering if there is any way to name the returned field something else within the function?

I tried using the RETURNS TABLE construct, but a strange thing happens with this. If you use it with only a single field, it will be converted to a simple RETURNS VARCHAR, or whichever type is used, once deployed. This is not ideal for certain things, such as DB backup/restore or bugfixes/modifications to the function.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to? This seems like a really weird requirement... can you explain more about the purpose of doing this? When you say *" it will be converted to a simple RETURNS VARCHAR, or whichever type is used, once deployed"* can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to specify the alias of a scalar return value within the function.

`RETURNS TABLE` *does* work, but only for `SELECT * FROM my_function()`. e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION one() RETURNS TABLE(colname integer) AS $$
    SELECT 1 AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM one();
 colname 
---------
       1
 (1 row)
```